# convert encoding via iconv linux

Tags: html, encoding, command-line-interface, arabic, iconv

I used to convert encoding via `iconv` but today i stopped by something new to me
I made a testcase to make my question clear :

the goal is convert `&#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1604;&#1602;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1579;&#1575;&#1604;&#1579;&#1577;` to its utf8 version :   الحلقة الثالثة

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title> this text is from arabic language   </title>
</head>
<body>
<p><span> &#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1604;&#1602;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1579;&#1575;&#1604;&#1579;&#1577;</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

tried to use encoding like `ASCII , LATIN1 , windows-1252` but with no luck 
how do i tell what is this type of encoding in order to convert it ??
both of  google translate + stackoverflow editor  was able to detect it and covert it ?

another example : this website http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php was able to convert the encoding correctly if i check the `Assume HTML (default: handle as plain text)`

what i am missing and those 3 websites was do it  to convert it correctly ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well  ,

after one day working , i have found my lost command  , its a package i had installed called [`ascii2uni`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/ascii2uni.1.html)

simply by : `sudo apt-get install ascii2uni`

and after some testing i was able to convert one file to unicode by using this command

`ascii2uni -a D source.html > target.html`

and i was able to convert it using **command line only**

cheers

Answer (score 2):

The idea is string substitution. Coding in `Python3`.

**parse decimal only:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'&#65;&#223;&#254;'
>>> r = re.compile(r'&#(\d+);')
>>> r.sub(lambda m:chr(int(m.group(1))), s)
'Aßþ'
```

**parse hex and decimal:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'&#x41;&#223;&#xFE;'
>>> r = re.compile(r'&#(x?)(\w+);')
>>> r.sub(lambda m:chr(int(m.group(2), 10 if not m.group(1) else 16)), s)
'Aßþ'
```

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers are called letter codes. There are special functions, related to url and html processing, that handle them - depending which language are you using.

---

*In PHP, there is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php  In other languages should be similar functions also*

Comment: I am sorry but am looking for cli command like my answer above, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
recode html..utf8
```

this should work too, but pls make sure you read the usage manual for recode, it recodes files in place if not told otherwise.